# line_profiler and kernprof does not work installed from pip and repro

Tags: python, line-profiler

I have tried what has been suggested. On the simplest of code, I get the familiar error that others have mentioned. The error is:

```
@profile
NameError: name 'profile' is not defined
```

on the minimal code:

```
@profile
def hello():
  print('Testing')

hello()
```

from the command line:

```
kernprof -l hello.py
```

I have imported `future` and I have even installed from the distribution outside of my virtualenv. This was a previous [suggestion](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/pull/25), as was importing future module.

So

```
import future
import cProfile

@profile
def hello():
  print('Testing')

hello()
```

also gives the same error. I cannot get this line profiler to work with pip or even from the raw repository. My versions are:

```
pip 8.1.2
python 2.7
```

Comment: where do you import the name `profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this my cloning the code from https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler and rebuilding and then calling the kernprof from the binary install location.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following snippet at the beginning of your python file:

```
import line_profiler
profile = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
```